# How to know what a warning is INSERT IGNORE?

Tags: python, mysql

Is it possible to somehow catch the warning, which is thrown when IGNORE?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve? Just to know whether the insert ignore actually did the insert or not?

Comment: Well, i be posting URLs in database, but this URL sometimes can not be unique. And I wanna know count of duplicates.

Comment: Then why not select to detect if has duplicates after insert?

Comment: Remove the URL uniqueness constraint, insert your URLs into the database, then afterwards do `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mytable WHERE url = "someurl"`